# one to many relationship "property does not exist on this collection instance"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to use the one to many relationship to populate a column in my table

/// this my view student.blade.php////

```
@foreach($student as $students)
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td class="sorting_1">{{$students->id}}</td>
   <td><img src="/img/{{$students->photo}}"
       style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%;">
   </td>
    <td>{{$students->matric_no}}</td>
    <td>{{$students->first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$students->last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$students->gender}}</td>
    <td>{{$students->DOB}}</td>
    <td>{{$students->classrm->id}}</td>
```

///student model ////

```
public function classrm(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class);
    }
```

/// class model///

```
public function student(){
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
```

/// student controller ///

```
public function index()
    {
        $student = Student::all();
        return view('student.Index', compact('student'));
    }
```

i expect it to display the values in my DB but throws an exception trying to get id of non-property

Comment: is your `classroom_id` field nullable in the DB? I suspect that the `$student->classrm` returns null, hence the reason for the exception. And btw, please change your naming convention, as `students` is plural and `student` is singular, which means you should iterate over `students` and print out each `student` data in a row.

Comment: yes my classroom_id is nullable ...

Comment: thanks for the naming convention tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the name of your relation to `classroom` in your student model:

```
public function classroom(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class);
}
```

Comment: P.S. try to follow the naming conventions. it's so important in laravel.